# How to remove frames, borders around objects in a wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf

Here on the screens, when I hover the cursor over the object, a gray border appears around itenter image description here
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIbkU.png)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AXAj.png)

```
<mah:MetroWindow  xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="Century Gothic"
    Title="Book Library" Height="660" Width="1250" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Image Width="200" Height="300" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

</mah:MetroWindow>

Comment: Could you add code that actually relates to attached photo?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting its borderthickness to 0.